# Handling Expand action with in XAML itself

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have list of stacklayouts to be dynamically loaded in XAML Xamarin Forms.

On tapping stacklayout, child elements need to expanded.

Below is what I have tried so far.

```
  <StackLayout Spacing="1">

                    <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource ExpandableHeaderStyle}">
                        <Label Text="Spec" FontSize="16" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageOne}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0,0,12,0">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer  Command ="{Binding ExpandViewFlagCommand}" CommandParameter="1"/>
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                        <StackLayout.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding Path=ImageOne}" Value="down_Arrow.png">
                                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding Path=ImageOne}" Value="up_Arrow.png">
                                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </StackLayout.Triggers>
                        <StackLayout Spacing="0" Style="{StaticResource ExpandableViewStyle}">
                            <Label Text="spec1" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16"/>
                            <Label Text="spec detail 1" FontSize="14"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Spacing="0" Style="{StaticResource ExpandableViewStyle}">
                            <Label Text="spec1" FontAttributes="Bold"  FontSize="16"/>
                            <Label Text="spec detail 1" FontSize="14"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                    <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource ExpandableHeaderStyle}">
                        <Label Text="Features" FontSize="16" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageTwo}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0,0,12,0">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer  Command ="{Binding ExpandViewFlagCommand}" CommandParameter="2"/>
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                        <StackLayout.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding Path=ImageTwo}" Value="down_Arrow.png">
                                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding Path=ImageTwo}" Value="up_Arrow.png">
                                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </StackLayout.Triggers>

                        <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource ExpandableViewOneItemStyle}">
                            <Image Source="bulletIcon.png" HeightRequest="6" WidthRequest="6"/>
                            <Label Text="feature 1" Style="{StaticResource ExpandableViewChildLabelStyle}" />
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout  Style="{StaticResource ExpandableViewOneItemStyle}">
                            <Image Source="bulletIcon.png" HeightRequest="6" WidthRequest="6"/>
                            <Label Text="feature 2" Style="{StaticResource ExpandableViewChildLabelStyle}"/>


                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                    <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource ExpandableHeaderStyle}">
                        <Label Text="Applications" FontSize="16" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageThree}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0,0,12,0">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer  Command ="{Binding ExpandViewFlagCommand}" CommandParameter="3"/>
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                        <StackLayout.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding Path=ImageThree}" Value="down_Arrow.png">
                                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding Path=ImageThree}" Value="up_Arrow.png">
                                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </StackLayout.Triggers>
                        <StackLayout  Style="{StaticResource ExpandableViewOneItemStyle}">
                            <Image Source="bulletIcon.png" HeightRequest="6" WidthRequest="6"/>
                            <Label Text="application 1" Style="{StaticResource ExpandableViewChildLabelStyle}"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout  Style="{StaticResource ExpandableViewOneItemStyle}">
                            <Image Source="bulletIcon.png" HeightRequest="6" WidthRequest="6"/>
                            <Label Text="application 2" Style="{StaticResource ExpandableViewChildLabelStyle}"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
```

I would like to make the number of stacklayouts to be displayed to be dynamic.

If I get to know changing the visibility of child elements within stack layout on the tap to control in XAML itself, that would also suffice.

Need help on this.

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a user control.

Perhaps you can create a user control that implements a single "node" using a stack layout or a grid then create a wrapper user control with bindable properties that generates and adds the required number of nodes in code behind the scenes.